# How to set color of background of selected text in dialogs in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I suspect the color scheme or theme has some bugs, because I can't see selected text in some dialogs. For example file rename:

[image]

`README` here is selected, `.md` is not. If I look hard enough, I see there is probably very slightly different background color, but on both my monitors it's barely noticeable and on a first (second and third) glance it looks like nothing is selected.

I don't want to change a whole color scheme/theme. I just want to know where to configure this specific thing, so I can pick by hand better background color (IDEA uses different color [easily distinguishable from background] for code editor and many other dialogs, not sure why some are special).

Comment: Try changing `Selection background` and `Selection foreground` under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor`

Comment: See if disabling third-party plugins fixes the issue https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html